# Excluding a ScalaTest test when calling my tests from within sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I want to write a test that calls a remote server and validates the response because the server may change (it's not under my control). To do this I figure I'd [give it a tag](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) (`RemoteTest`) and then [exclude it when calling the runner](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#filtering):

```
sbt> test-only * -- -l RemoteTest
```

However, when doing this all my tests are run, including `RemoteTest`. How do I call the runner from within sbt so that it is excluded?

Comment: While it doesn't answer to your question in any way, It is good practice to use stubs and [mocks](http://scalamock.org/) for such changing things.

Comment: I basically do. But I still want to know if the API changes on me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the following:-

```
package com.test

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Tag

object SlowTest extends Tag("com.mycompany.tags.SlowTest")
object DbTest extends Tag("com.mycompany.tags.DbTest")

class TestSuite extends FlatSpec {

  "The Scala language" must "add correctly" taggedAs(SlowTest) in {
      val sum = 1 + 1
      assert(sum === 2)
    }

  it must "subtract correctly" taggedAs(SlowTest, DbTest) in {
    val diff = 4 - 1
    assert(diff === 3)
  }
}
```

To exclude DbTest tag, you would do:-

```
test-only * -- -l com.mycompany.tags.DbTest
```

Note that you'll need to include the full tag name.  If it's still not working for you, would you mind sharing part of source code that's not working?

Comment: Ha, so simple! I totally missed that it needs to be the fully qualified name.